# Can I jump out of a current executing function?

Tags: assembly, x86

A problem from the [buflab of CSAPP](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/labs.html). I'm asked to key in some exploit code long enough to corrupt the stack. In phase 2 I need to first change the value of a global var named **global_value** and then call a function named **bang**. However, it works only if I push the address of bang into stack and then return.

```
#codes before set the value of global_value
movl $0x12345678,%eax         /* 0x12345678 is the address of bang */
push %eax
ret
```

If I use a direct jump like

```
#codes before set the value of global_value
jmp 0x12345678
```

Then I got totally lost at somewhere like 0x5abcdefg with gdb. Anyone can help? Does this have anything to do with the addressing of mode?

Comment: `<C-rant>use longjmp()</C-rant>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know `jmp 0x12345678` really is `jmp 0x12345678`?

All non-far jumps that take their jump address from the immediate operand are relative to the location of the instruction immediately following the `jmp` instruction.

So, if you have in memory the following:

```
Address    Contents
0x55555555 E9 78 56 34 12
```

Then this is a jump to 0x55555555 + 5 (jmp instruction length) + 0x12345678 = 0x6789ABD2.

OTOH, if you have this:

```
Address    Contents
0x55555555 E9 1E 01 DF BC
```

Then this is a jump to 0x55555555 + 5 (jmp instruction length) + 0xBCDF011E = 0x12345678.

Comment: One more question....
How would the assembler know my return is a near one or far one? Will a true return to 0x55555555 be guarteened by `ret 0x5555555`?